# Why WebView shows local .html without .css and .js?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to display local .html with .css and .js by WebView. Here is my code:

```
    WebView webView = new WebView();
    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.load(Main.class.getResource("/dashboard/index.html").toExternalForm());
    Stage webViewStage = new Stage();
    webViewStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(webView)));
    webViewStage.show();
```

And that folder structure where .html located:

[image]

But my local web page loaded like this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34339752/2740650 might help

Comment: @user2740650 thanks, but in index.html are to many links to .css and .js files, that by itself contains a lot of links (i.e. bootstrap). By the way web pages from the web loaded normally.

Comment: Hmm, what does `Main.class.getResource("/dashboard/index.html").toExternalForm()` look like?  If it's not `file://something` then that might explain why it doesn't work for local URLs.

Comment: @user2740650 file:/Users/anahel/Documents/Projects/IdeaProjects/sql-load-test-without-maven/out/production/sql-load-test-without-maven/dashboard/index.html

Comment: That doesn't look quite right.  I'd expect "file:///".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703884/trying-to-load-a-local-page-into-javafx-webengine has a comment "note no leading / on the path" so you could try that.  Also, verify that you can open the url in your own browser (Chrome or whatever), and try pasting that full URL in as a test case.

Comment: @user2740650 my app shows page without .css and .js both with "file:///" and "file:/". My browser shows page correct both with "file:///" and "file:/".

Comment: It might be important that I build project without maven